# Is there a way to mimic sending text messages to ios simulator using xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I am trying to implement functionality to auto read and auto-fill otp in react native. I have implemented the functionality, but now I want to test it. Android Simulator provides a functionality to send messages to emulator as shown below [image]

I want to know if there is a similar functionality that is provided by xcode to send messages to ios simulators?